# Complicated regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I cant find a way to parse a string of the form

```
"(info1) something-uninteresting [info2, info22] s.u. [info3] s.u. (info4, info5, info6)"
```

correctly. I want an output just like

```
 Information Nr.0: info1
 Information Nr.1:  something-uninteresting 
 Information Nr.2: info2,
 Information Nr.3:  info22
 Information Nr.4:  s.u. 
 Information Nr.5: info3
 Information Nr.6:  s.u. 
 Information Nr.7: info4,
 Information Nr.8:  info5,
 Information Nr.9:  info6
```

but without the commas at the end (see information nr.7 or 8 for example).
my current approach is

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\[(\\])][^\\])\\[(,]*[^\\])\\[(]");
```

every help will be appreciated

Comment: why did i get a downvote ?

Comment: What trouble are you getting with your current approach?

Comment: the commas at the end, as said in the post. (see information nr. 7 or 8)

Comment: what kind of hater voted every single answer down ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    String text = "(info1) something-uninteresting [info2, info22] s.u. [info3] s.u. (info4, info5, info6)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(" ?[\\w-.]+");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

Result:

```
info1
 something-uninteresting
info2
 info22
 s.u.
info3
 s.u.
info4
 info5
 info6
```

Comment: it produces the same output as my current version

Comment: Fixed. Now it removes the commas.

Comment: yes it does, thank you for your effort, but the answer of Keppil is slightly better, because it has no leading withespaces in the output. but thanks

Comment: Just for the record Anubhava - who posted a good answer - removed his answer because it wouldn't allow spaces in the `something-uninteresting`. This regex doesn't allow spaces in your `something-uninteresting` either.

Comment: @OGHaza I added the result. There's the space before the 'something-uninteresting'.

Comment: Note that you don't have to escape `-` and `.` in character classes. `[\\w\\-\\.]` can be simplified to `[\\w-.]`.

Comment: On the now deleted answer OP commented that `something-uninteresting` can include anything except for `[](),`. My point is that with this regex you would have to literally add every single allowable character into the class like `[\\w-.$%^&*!@;'"\\\\/~ ]` etc. OP's original solution that was fixed by adding 3 `,`'s into his character classes already avoided this problem.

Comment: I missed OP comments. If only []() must be removed, then use @keppil solution but putting " ?" before, to match spaces too.

Comment: Using space in regex pattern is not good habit. You should use `\\x20` instead

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to collect all separating characters and look for sequences without them. This code produces the matches you want:

```
String text = "(info1) something-uninteresting [info2, info22] s.u. [info3] s.u. (info4, info5, info6)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\[\\](),]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: this looks good. i will do a few more tests and if everything is fine i will accept your answer

Comment: the only problem is, that if the first bracket for example looks like this [infopart1 infopart2] it will split them, although they are in the same bracket and therefore should stay together.

Comment: Changed the expression by removing the whitespace in the character class. Now it works exactly as your example in the question, and won't split [infopart1 infopart2].

Comment: i think it is because of the withespaces between the brackets it produces information which is empty. (information nr. 1 and 3 for example are empty), but thank you all for your effort

Comment: I don't get any empty matches, so I don't really understand what the problem is. But if you have found a good solution, all is well.

Comment: i derped a little, because i tested it on a slightly other string. that has brackets followed by another brackets. something like "(info1 info2) (info) [pretty] [well]" .. and then you get the empty matches. sorry for that stupid "mistake" of mine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"\\((.*)\\)\\s*(.*)\\s*\\[(.*),\\s*(.*)]\\s*(.*)\\s*\\[(.*)]\\s*(.*)\\s*\\((.*),\\s*(.*),\\s*(.*)\\)"
```

Here I took your input and:

- replaced spaces by \s*
- replaced group of words to be captured together by .*
- escaped problematic characters with a \
- doubled each \ because Java will try to interpret them otherwise

I will also consider not capturing uninteresting parts by using: `(?:)`, and making each `.*` more robust by replacing them by the adequate character classes (like `[a-z]*` or `\S*` ... you will know what your data is like).

Also, you could change you current regexp by specifying how your data looks like instead of how it doesn't looks like:

```
"\W\w\W"
```

Of course, if your data is composed of word characters only (`[a-zA-Z_0-9]`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding just 3 characters to your current regex:

```
[^,\\[(\\])][^,\\])\\[(]*[^,\\])\[(]
  ^           ^            ^
```

Each character class is the same, so if we call that character class `A` the pattern can be represented as `AA*A` which can always be simplified to `AA+`:

```
[^,\\[(\\])][^,\\[(\\])]+
```

However that still requires at least 2 characters in the match, which is probably unintentional, so you can remove the first character class leaving just `A+`:

```
[^,\\[(\\])]+
```

[RegExr](http://regexr.com?37d9i)

Comment: this is not a valid expression, and by the way what does OP mean ?

Comment: I forgot to escape the backslashes in the second one (this is a requirement of Java rather than regex). Fixed now. OP = Original Poster or some variation of that.

Comment: i think it is because of the withespaces between the brackets it produces information which is empty. (information nr. 1 and 3 for example are empty)

Comment: Seems unlikely, the `+` should mean that the match must be at least 1 character long. It works on RegExr, RegexPal and in a javascript console anyway. Are you using it in exactly the same way you used your original regex?

Comment: right. i tested it on a other piece, which contains two following brackets like "(info1 info2) (info)", and then there is a problem.

Comment: True it won't work for that. You'd need to add `(?!\s)` at the start. So: `(?!\s)[^\[\(\]\),]+` [then it works](http://regexr.com?37da4)

Comment: unfortunately its again not a valid expression in java

Comment: Each time I post a \, its me forgetting you're using java. I mean a \\ in Java so add `(?!\\s)` to the start `(?!\\s)[^,\\[(\\])]+`

Comment: that actually works perfectly as well. thank you for your commitment

Comment: No problem. If you're expecting spaces or any sort of special character like `;/\"'*&%^$£@` or unicode characters in your `something-uninteresting` the other answer will break. IMO you were going down the correct route to begin with which is why I stuck with it.

Comment: ahhh btw, I just realised your old regex worked with the `) (` example right? Thats because as I mentioned you were requiring 2+ characters so alternatively you could use `[^,\\[(\\])]{2,}` to do the same thing instead of that `(?!\\s)`. No need to reply